# Create React App skips router in public directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I have an app created via Create React App. Inside the app in `public` directory is directory `app-b` with another SPA.

When navigates to URL `/` the main app renders.

When navigates to URL `/app-b` the second app renders.

However, when navigates to URL `/app-b/some/path` the main app renders with 404 obviously.

How to, and where configure Creat React App to skip main React router when requesting `/app-b/*` path?

Comment: Routes are evaluated in order - put your more specific route before the more general one.

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5081) could help

Comment: Thanks for answers but the second app is inside the `public` directory - it is not a part of the main app.